# golang reverse proxy for google.com

Tags: http, go, reverse-proxy

I am trying to play with golang's reverse proxy. I am trying to create a reverse proxy on my localhost that would forward my request to google.com and get back with the response. Even though this seems a simple task, I am not able to get a correct result. I am getting a google 404 response saying that the url "/" is not found

My code

```
package main
import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httputil"
    "net/url"
)

func main() {
    gogle, _ := url.Parse("http://www.google.com")
    proxy := httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy(gogle)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":12345", proxy))
}
```

what is that I am missing?

Answer (score -2):

it turns out it is because google uses https.